# Edge 17 - PushManager.Subscribe fails with AbortError

Tags: push-notification, microsoft-edge, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Edge 17 supports Service Workers, and apparently also PushManager.

However, even though my implementation of Push Notifications works in all browsers that support them, it does not seem to work with Edge.

```
if ('PushManager' in window) {
    registration.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array('xxxxxxx')
    })
    .then(function(subscription) {
        console.log('All good');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

This fails in 'catch' with:

> [object DOMException]: {code: 20, message: "AbortError", name:
>   "AbortError"}

Is this a known issue with Edge? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that applicationServerKey is having a value and it is not "null" or "undefined"?

Comment: @WarPro Yes, it works for ALL other browsers.

Comment: I have the exact same Issue with Edge. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Nevius - nope... I guess this is just Microsoft creating their own "standards", so we must need to do something completely different than other browsers, to get it to work for their browser.

Comment: We had the same issue, it was caused by DNS misconfiguration in our server. Make sure your server can be publicly resolved, then notifications should work.

Comment: @DreamOfMirrors could you please clarify what do you mean? My server is 100% public, with loads of users all the time accessing it. What exactly is the DNS record that was misconfigured on your server?

Comment: I think*** <- operative, I think
Edge currently does not have the Windows Notification service wired up. So while it is Beta my guess is push appears to be supported, but in reality isn't yet.

Comment: The Edge that I was referring to isn't in BETA, no. There is a new Edge that is currently being tested that is based on Chromium (finally!). I'm expecting that to work better, since they will now follow the proper standards.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error so I took at look at this code that works:

https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/

What fixed it for me was this part:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(/* registration function here*/
```

Comment: Good point, and I think that should be the better thing to do. I made the change, yet I still get the exact same error. `navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js');  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {`

Comment: The only other issue I had is if userVisibleOnly wasn't set to true.  It seems to be working pretty consistently right now.

Comment: Yup - I have userVisibleOnly to true since the very beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same issue on Edge, However was working fine on Chrome, and tried multiple options with different systems as well, thinking its the problem with my code, however it started working in some time exact same code working i.e. subscription object was getting created.

<< This would most likely happen if service provider is not available or not able to responding with subscription object successfully>>

```
reg.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeParams)
        .then(function (subscription) {
            console.log('[subscribe] : user subscribed');
        })
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in my example code above, and doesn't work. Hopefully this will be fixed when Microsoft releases Edge based on Chromium :)

Comment: This is not the problem with the browser I believe but the availability of push service provider and there API, subscription object gets created only when push service provider responds with subscription object.